# Remote Spark ; Java; HDFS (Apache Spark (2.4.4)

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

### Setup

I've got Apache Spark (2.4.4), running on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-65-generic x86_64))
I also have hadoop(hdfs) running on the same Linux box. (hostname: ikarakas.fritz.box, IP:192.168.188.76)

My driver application (in Java; 1.8.0_73) is on a Mac box.

Here is some excerpt from my driver application

```
public void startUp() {
    System.out.println(getNowISO() + "-----TEST: startUp");

    String sparkMaster = "ikarakas.fritz.box";

    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Ilker's Analyzer")
            .setMaster("spark://" + sparkMaster + ":7077");

    spark = SparkSession
            .builder()
            .config(conf)
            .config("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "UTC")
            .getOrCreate();


    l16DataSet = spark.read().json("hdfs://192.168.188.76:9000/user/hadoop/l16data.json");
    // ...
}
```

### Problem

My application can never complete the spark.read.json(...) statement.

When I check the Spark Web Job monitoring interface, I see that my job is stuck on that line number; e.g.

```
org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.json(DataFrameReader.scala:325)
spark.Analyzer.startUp(Analyzer.java:67)
spark.Analyzer.test(Analyzer.java:365)
spark.Analyzer.main(Analyzer.java:396)
```

All I am trying to do is, run my job at the remote master, and, as part of that, be able to load a file from the hdfs.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: what is the value of `fs.default.name` in your `core-site.xml`? Is it `hdfs://192.168.188.76:9000`?

Comment: No. I am listening on all interfaces; so it is hdfs://0.0.0.0:9000

Comment: `fs.default.name` (or `fs.defaultFS` in newer versions) is "The name of the default file system. A URI whose scheme and authority determine the FileSystem implementation." The URL which datanodes use to find find NameNode,